# How would I push a object within a object in JavaScript using push function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to rework some of my API data locally on my systems, but I'm having trouble in JavaScript, I have a loop running for each name on a table, I wanna basically go from this

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "USERNAME",
    "Status": 1234,
    "information": "Has something here"
  }
  ...
]
```

To something like this

```json
[
  "USERNAME": {
    "Status": 1234,
    "information: "Has something here"
  }
  ...
]
```

How I'm currently running my code is as follows

```js
let array = []
rows.forEach((row) => {
  let obj = {
    Name: row.name,
    Status: 1234,
    "information": "Has Something here"
  }
  array.push(obj)
}
```

I've already tried a few things including building the array first with the names and adding the objects under each name which seems I'm unable to in the end.

I've also tried pushing to the array as follows `array.push({[row.name]: {"Status": 1234, "information": "Has something here"}` but the outcome is not desirable

```json
[
  {
    "USERNAME": {
      "Status": 1234,
      "information": "Has something here"
    }
  }
  ...
]
```

But still I don't output as follows

```json
[
  "USERNAME": {
    "Status": 1234,
    "information": "Has something here"
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: "To something like this ```[
  "USERNAME": {
    "Status": 1234,``` " — That is nonsense. Arrays (`[]`) are a list of values. Objects (`{}`) have `key: value` pairs. You're asking for an array that has the shape of an object.

Comment: I realized that at last second as of this moment, but there isn't a push function built into objects sadly, and that's why I might've defaulted down to an array not thinking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear, but I think you might be looking for one of these approaches:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "Name": "USERNAME",
    "Status": 1234,
    "information": "Has something here"
  },
  {
    "Name": "USERNAME2",
    "Status": 5678,
    "information": "Has something here"
  },
]

console.log(Object.fromEntries(arr.map(({Name,...o})=>[Name, o])))

console.log(arr.map(({Name,...o})=>({[Name]: o})))
```

Comment: Funny enough, this is the cleanest solution to my issue, all I needed was to generate the array and push this at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**Note that the output is an object `{}` and not an array `[]`.**

Given a sample set:

```
const data = [
  {
    "Name": "USERNAME1",
    "Status": 1234,
    "information": "Has something here"
  },
  {
    "Name": "USERNAME2",
    "Status": 5678,
    "information": "Has something else here"
  }
];
```

You can use:

```
const newData = {};
for (const obj of data) {
  const { Name, ...rest } = obj;
  newData[Name] = rest;
}
```

or

```
const newData = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.Name] = { ...item };
  delete obj[item.Name].Name;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

This will produce an output:

```
{
  "USERNAME1": {
    "Status": 1234,
    "information": "Has something here"
  },
  "USERNAME2": {
    "Status": 5678,
    "information": "Has something else here"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to build an array with keys. In JSON, only objects: `{}` can have the notation of `key: value, key: value, ...`. An array: `[]` can only have the notation of `value, value, ...` The example you gave of an array of objects is the only way (that I can think of) to achieve what you want.

Comment: It's an object, not JSON, which is a string

Comment: I noticed that right as I posted it, though right when I did, I did step back and tried pushing to an object, but it seems that there's no push function on objects, only arrays

Comment: You should be pushing an object into an array. Alternatively, instead of using an array and push, you could use an object, and the notation: object[<name>] = <value>;